# How regroup all comments on my index page?

Tags: facebook, comments

I use FB Comments with this code

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/fr_FR/all.js#xfbml=1">
</script>
<fb:comments publish_feed="true" href="http://infoactu.fr/xxxxxx.html" num_posts="25" width="600"></fb:comments>
```

All my pages have a different URL so I get different comments. But on my index page, I want to show all the comments of the pages.

Can you help me?  I must develop with php?  With what?  I don't find on FB comment.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing this then you will need to query the facebook data yourself and post the results to the page.

so sending requests to:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/comments/?ids={YOUR_URL}.
```

then you will need to merge these results and show them on your index page. I believe you can have multiple urls in one request but have not tested this. you may have to aggregate multiple requests

Hope this helps

Oh see here for more docs:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/